# datepicker is not a function -

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm trying run a JS script in Thymeleaf, but it`s not working. In browser I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (3:117)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

JS Script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datebirth").datepicker({
            maxDate:'0'
        });
    } );

</script>
```

Where is a conflict?

Comment: `datepicker` requires jQuery UI in addition to jQuery.

Comment: Have you loaded a datepicker jQuery plugin library?

Comment: When I'm adding jQuery UI, I've got new error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'step' of undefined
    at String.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.js:1951)
    at each (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Function.color.hook (jquery-ui.js:1913)
    at jquery-ui.js:1963
    at jquery-ui.js:2005
    at jquery-ui.js:14
    at jquery-ui.js:16`

Comment: try to use jquery.min instead of .slim

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Thymeleaf tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart) in order to use script inlining.

As an example you can try:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(function() {
          $("#datebirth").datepicker({
            maxDate:'0'
          });
        });
      /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Comment: How about an explanation instead of some code dump we have to play spot-the-difference with?